# LLC initial current and voltage estimate from the equation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, math, llc-converter

There is a paper called
[Real Time Hardware-in-Loop Implementation of LLC Resonant Converter at Worst Operating Point Based on Time Domain Analysis](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/15/10/3634)

I am trying to derive equations 25 and 26 from this paper, but I got some problems,
Does anyone know how to derive these two equations based on the eq 10 11 12 17 18 19.
In this paper, they don't tell the reader how to get the result. so I am curious about how to do that.

[image]

[image]

[image]